# How to solve `fileName::stripInvalid() called for invalid fileName CalibreLibrary` in OpenFOAM?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, c

I installed OpenFOAM on my Linux Mint. When I run `simpleFoam`, the following prompt appears:

```
~ ❯❯❯ simpleFoam
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
  =========                 |
  \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox
   \\    /   O peration     | Website:  https://openfoam.org
    \\  /    A nd           | Version:  10
     \\/     M anipulation  |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Build  : 10-c4cf895ad8fa
Exec   : simpleFoam
Date   : Mar 31 2023
Time   : 14:34:11
Host   : "Milotron"
PID    : 29077
I/O    : uncollated
Case   : /home/milo
nProcs : 1
sigFpe : Enabling floating point exception trapping (FOAM_SIGFPE).
fileModificationChecking : Monitoring run-time modified files using timeStampMaster (fileModificationSkew 10)
allowSystemOperations : Allowing user-supplied system call operations

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
Create time

fileName::stripInvalid() called for invalid fileName CalibreLibrary
    For debug level (= 2) > 1 this is considered fatal
fish: Job 1, 'simpleFoam' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

What should I do with `fileName::stripInvalid() called for invalid fileName CalibreLibrary`?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue and after stumbling upon this question I figured it out. Turns out OpenFOAM folders and files need to start with a lower case letter. The name of your file is 'CalibreLibrary' and starts with an upper case. To fix this problem the name should be 'calibreLibrary'.

If you look for the openFOAM tutorial directory you will notice that most folders and files start with lowercase.